# One error message instead of few for Zend validator

Tags: php, zend-framework, validation, email

I have the next element:

```
$email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
$email->setAttribs(array('class' => 'input-text', 'id' => 'email'))
        ->setLabel($this->view->translate('Email'))
        ->setValue(null)
        ->setRequired(true)
        ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress())
        ->setDecorators($emailMessageDecorators);
```

If there are more than one mistake in the email address, some errors are displaying. Like this:

```
'fff.fgdf' is no valid hostname for email address 'as@fff.fgdf'
'fff.fgdf' appears to be a DNS hostname but cannot match TLD against known list
'fff.fgdf' appears to be a local network name but local network names are not allowed
```

How can I set only 1 message? I have tryed setMessage(string), but it shows 3 same errors. Thanks. Sorry for my english. Peace & love)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the past, I had to make a custom validator for that:

```
/**
 * The standard email address validator with a single, simple message
 */
class App_Validate_EmailAddressSimpleMessage extends Zend_Validate_EmailAddress
{
    const COMMON_MESSAGE = 'Invalid email address';

    protected $_messageTemplates = array(
        self::INVALID            => self::COMMON_MESSAGE,
        self::INVALID_FORMAT     => self::COMMON_MESSAGE,
        self::INVALID_HOSTNAME   => self::COMMON_MESSAGE,
        self::INVALID_MX_RECORD  => self::COMMON_MESSAGE,
        self::INVALID_SEGMENT    => self::COMMON_MESSAGE,
        self::DOT_ATOM           => self::COMMON_MESSAGE,
        self::QUOTED_STRING      => self::COMMON_MESSAGE,
        self::INVALID_LOCAL_PART => self::COMMON_MESSAGE,
        self::LENGTH_EXCEEDED    => self::COMMON_MESSAGE,
    );

}
```

Then called using:

`$email->addValidator(new App_Validate_EmailAddressSimpleMessage());`

If you just want to use the same syntax as usual:

`$email->addValidator('EmailAddress');`

but have it use this validator, then you can change the classname/filename from  `EmailAddressSimpleMessage` to simply `EmailAddress` and register the prefix `App_Validate_` with the form/elements.

Even better would probably be to allow this class to accept an optional constructor parameter for the message you want, but I was going quick-and-dirty at the time.

Comment: Not a good solution as there are many validators beyond just the email address validator.

Comment: Indeed, the solution is limited to only `Zend_Validate_EmailAddress`, which was the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, you can call setErrorMessages() to set a single error message on the form element, rather than calling setMessages() on each individual validator:

```
$form->addElement('password', 'password', array(
    'label' => 'New password:',
    'required' => true,
    'validators' => array(
        array('StringLength', false, 6),
        // more validators
    ),
    'errorMessages' => array('Invalid password.')
));
```

Comment: I know it. I have too validators for my element (NotEmpty and Email). And I want to get 2 types of error messages ('Value is required' and 'Invalid Email').

Answer (score 1):

This is an example(I hope it helps) :

```
$email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('emailid');

$email->setLabel("Email-Adress :* ")
      ->setOptions(array('size' => 20))
      ->setRequired(true)
      ->addFilter('StripTags')
      ->addFilter('StringTrim')
      ->addValidator('EmailAddress')
      ->getValidator('EmailAddress')->setMessage("Please enter a valid e-mail address.");
```

Comment: no. I have made it too. See my question. It displays 3 same messages.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer, by using $breakChainOnFailure = true:

```
addValidator($nameOrValidator, $breakChainOnFailure = false, array $options = null);
```

Cited: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.validators.errors

Answer (score -1):

You using this example:

```
$email_validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
$email = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('email');
$email->setRequired('true')
      ->setLabel('Email: ')
      ->setDecorators(array(array('ViewHelper'), array('Errors')))
      ->addValidator($email_validator);
```

Comment: And what? Your answer is useless. Zend_Validate_EmailAddress creates 3 validators. And each validator has his own errors. And if we do ->setErrorMessage('bla bla bla') it makes 3 same errors.