# Overwrite Zend Validation Message

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form-element

How can I overwrite Zend validation messages in my code below.

```
$validatee = array(
                        'email' => $email,
                );
        $validator = array(
                    'email' => array(
                                'EmailAddress',
                                'messages' => array('emailAddressInvalidFormat',"Invalid Email Address")
                            )
                    );

        $emailValidator = new Zend_Filter_Input(null, $validator,$validatee);
```

I tried doing that but the message doesn't change and always output

```
"no valid email address in the basic format local-part@hostname"
```

please help!

Comment: Are you sure this error message is thrown by Zend_FIlter_input?? Isnt this thrown and can be set by an instance of Zend_Validate_EmailAddress?

Comment: I'm not using zend forms for this. I am using Zend_Filter_Input  to check if email address is available for registration or not. But before I compare it to my database, it must be validated first as an email address. And yup, the error above is generated.

Comment: i posted a fix, try my answer below

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036024/one-error-message-instead-of-few-for-zend-validator/6041524#6041524 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942674/zend-emailaddress-validation-returning-multiple-errors/7943869#7943869

Answer (score 0):

Change your $validator to ::

```
       can you try adding 
$validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();
$validator->setMessage(
    'A valid email is required',
    Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID
); 

and then use in Zend_filter_input?
```

Comment: Still not working. My version is 1.11.11. Very weird because I was able to customize the validation for NotEmpty.
$validators = array('username' => array(
      'NotEmpty',
                        'messages'=>array('Username field required.')
    ),
    'password' => array(
      'NotEmpty',
                        'messages'=>array('Password field required.')
    )
   );

Comment: try my edited ans.. Its kinda wierd why setting messages doesnt work!!

Comment: Server error..I think I have to include tha path to Zend_Validate. How can I include it to my controller/action?

Comment: Dont u use Zend_autoregister to autoload classes?? 

you can do require_once("Zend/Validate/EmailAddress.php");